# Escape comma in Scrapy Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Working on a scrapy spider.

I have this html :

```
<div class="sliderContent">
<p>some content, some other content</p>
<p>some content, some other content</p>
<p>some content, some other content</p>
<p>some content, some other content</p>
</div>
```

My xpath :

```
item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()
```

I want to escape the comma in `<p>` and extract all the content, keeping the html. I tried this :

```
    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
        item = LuItem()
        item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()[0].replace(',','\,')
        yield item
```

This works for the first `<p>`, obviously, but how can i achieve this for all the `<p>` ?

Starting with python, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: please add website url. i think you can try some thing like this:                  >>> a= 'some content, some other content'
>>> a.replace(',','/')
'some content/ some other content'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing result is a list and you are modifying only the first element in the list [0], you need go through the whole list of your description:

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
        item = LuItem()
        item['Description'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="content"]/div/div[@class="sliderContent"]//p').extract()
        item['Description'] = [ ''.join(field.split(',')) for field in item.get('Description', [])]
        yield item
```